# Error in template function

Tags: c++, templates

What is the problem with this code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T max(T X, T Y)
{
    return (X > Y) ? X : Y;
}

int main()
{
    int x = max(5,6);
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
overload.C: In function 'int main()':
overload.C:19: error: call of overloaded 'max(int, int)' is ambiguous
overload.C:12: note: candidates are: T max(T, T) [with T = int]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2  /bits/stl_algobase.h:206: note:                 const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`max` is already defined in standard library. Remove `using namespace std` and it should work.

Comment: +1 And here's the link, just for a reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max

Comment: +1: But maybe add a remark about that the standard does not forbid standard-headers to `#include` other standard-headers, which causes `<algorithm>` to creep in.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the fully-qualified name `::max` to refer to the declaration in the global namespace. But removing the `using` would be more polite; and using `std::max` rather than writing your own version might be even better.

Comment: As far as I know, constructing a good compiler error detection and reporting system is a very complex task! Templates make it even harder!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `max` is already declared by the standrad library. Try not importing the namespace.